# Create specific pairs from two lists in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am currently trying to create specific pairs from two python lists:

```
Input:
l1 = ["fc1", "fc2"]
l2 = ["fh1", "fh2"]

Expected output:

outl1 = [["fc1","fh1"],["fc2","fh2"]]
outl2 = [["fc2","fh1"],["fc1","fh2"]]
```

You'll have guessed from this example that a "fc*" must be matched with a "fh*" and that any occurance of the list cannot be repeated in the final output.

I must admit I am quite confused by all the documentation if found online about zip, enumerate, itertools etc...

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Does order matter? E.g. are `['fc2', 'fh1']` & `['fh1', 'fc2']` considered equivalent?

Comment: @jpp no order does not matter. Sorry I forgot to specify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you want to create all possible lists of pairs ('fci', 'fhj'), such that in each list all the 'fci' appear only once and the same for 'fhj'.

You can use `itertools.permuations` to achieve this. I generalized your example to include 3  elements per list.

```
from itertools import permutations 

A = ["fc1", "fc2", "fc3"]
B = ["fh1", "fh2", "fh3"]

B_permuations = permutations(B)

for perm in B_permuations:
    print([[a, b] for a, b in zip(A, perm)])
```

This will give you 
​

```
[['fc1', 'fh1'], ['fc2', 'fh2'], ['fc3', 'fh3']]
[['fc1', 'fh1'], ['fc2', 'fh3'], ['fc3', 'fh2']]
[['fc1', 'fh2'], ['fc2', 'fh1'], ['fc3', 'fh3']]
[['fc1', 'fh2'], ['fc2', 'fh3'], ['fc3', 'fh1']]
[['fc1', 'fh3'], ['fc2', 'fh1'], ['fc3', 'fh2']]
[['fc1', 'fh3'], ['fc2', 'fh2'], ['fc3', 'fh1']]
```

Comment: You understand it corretly indeed ! Thanks for the clear answer and the extrapolation to 3 elements.

Comment: Or, more succinctly, you can use the generator expression `res = (list(map(list, zip(A, perm))) for perm in permutations(B))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` method by passing the both given lists as arguments.

For achieving the `outl2` list you should use `zip` method which accepts two `arguments`: the `l1` list, but *reversed* and `l2` list.

`zip` method makes an *iterator* that **aggregates** elements from each of the *iterables*.

With the other words, *zip* returns an `iterator` of **tuples**, where the *i-th* tuple contains the *i-th* element from each of the argument sequences or **iterables**.

```
l1 = ["fc1", "fc2"]
l2 = ["fh1", "fh2"]

print([[a,b] for a,b in zip(l1,l2)])
print([[a,b] for a,b in zip(reversed(l1),l2)])
```

Output

```
[['fc1', 'fh1'], ['fc2', 'fh2']]
[['fc2', 'fh1'], ['fc1', 'fh2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

if `enumerate`, `zip` and such is overwhelming at first use a simple `for` loops

```
l1 = ["fc1", "fc2"]
l2 = ["fh1", "fh2"]

a = []
for i1 in l1:
    a.append([[i1,i2] for i2 in l2])

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

output

```
[['fc1', 'fh1'], ['fc1', 'fh2']]
[['fc2', 'fh1'], ['fc2', 'fh2']]
```